# Add styling to moment.format() date

Tags: angular, typescript, date, styles, momentjs

I have to display a date like Wednesday, **February 19** using a pipe that takes the date value and the format as inputs

```
moment(value).format(chosenFormat)
```

but I need to add style to February 19 - bold. Currently I splitted in `dayName` and `shortDate`, but I may have problems for different languages with the order. So I have to use `longDate`. Is there any way I can add styling to a part of the long date?

I tried `"longDate": "<strong>dddd</strong>, MMMM D"` for the token but it's not working.